# insert into table where if not in list

Tags: sql, mysql

Can anybody help me with the syntax?

```
insert into history (company,partnumber,price) 
 values ('blah','IFS0090','0.00') 
 if company NOT IN ('blah','blah2','blah3','blah4','blah4') 
 and partnumber='IFS0090';
```

Background:
I have a history table which stores daily company, products and prices. But sometimes a company will remove itself for a few days. Complicating the issue is because I'm only saving daily CHANGES to prices only and not snapshotting the entire days list (the data would be huge) when I display the data the company will still come up for the previous days price. So I need to do something like this, where a 0.00 price means they're no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO HISTORY
  (company, partnumber, price)
 SELECT 'blah', 'IFS0090','0.00'
   FROM HISTORY h
  WHERE h.company NOT IN ('blah','blah2','blah3','blah4','blah4') 
    AND h.partnumber = 'IFS0090'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two completely different concepts in your statement. Choose one:

- Either you want to INSERT constant values (in that case make your checks in your programming language and generate the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` accordingly)
- or insert the filtered contents of another table.

The latter is possible in MySQL (that's the [`INSERT ... SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)), the query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO history (...)
SELECT ...
FROM liveTable
INNER JOIN moreTables ...
--# this is a regular SELECT statement, as you might have guessed by now
WHERE company NOT IN ('blah','blah2','blah3','blah4','blah4') 
AND partnumber='IFS0090';
```